# Simple Facebook status return using FQL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

I'm trying to create a box on the side of a page that displays the 6 latest posts from a Twitter account and Facebook page. Twitter is working exactly how I want it to - Facebook is not.

The way I am doing it at the moment is to fetch the latest statuses using FQL as JSON usin cURL, caching them on the server, then displaying them in the same way as I am the tweets in the actual box.

My problem lies with the access token. I went away last night with it working, came back this morning and noticed that the modified date of my cached file hadn't changed. I checked the cached error file (where the fetched JSON gets dumped if it doesn't contain the data I need) and I had a session expired error. I then created a small function that uses cURL (3 cURL calls or one box, I know - urgh) to retrieve a new access token using the this URL:

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=XXX&client_secret=XXXX

But I now get an error that a User Session is required, but all I want to do is to read the latest posts, that isn't user dependant at all. I really want to avoid using the Facebook SDK if possible.

Tl;dr - FQL seems to require users to log in even just to read statuses off of a set page's wall - what's the correct way of getting this data that doesn't require a user session (preferably without using the SDK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to get the status from a User account then you will require a valid user access token.

If you're getting statuses from a Fan Page then you just require a valid app access token - which can be obtained from:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
```

You can then use the returned access token to get the statuses from the target Fan Page.

---

> SELECT id,status_id,message,time FROM status WHERE uid = XXXX LIMIT 6

You're querying by user id so that will require a valid user access token.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm still getting the 'Requires user session' error (102) even using the access token that URL provides. I'm thinking it may be something to do with my query - I might be getting something that's restricted? Here's the query I'm using:

SELECT id,status_id,message,time FROM status WHERE uid = XXXX LIMIT 6

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Querying the 'stream' table instead of the 'posts' table works